# C'è un errore in un'accezione di "degenerazione" del dizionario Zingarelli per cui la marca d'uso "mat." dovrebbe essere "fis."?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, vocabulary, mathematics

Posto qui questa domanda perché, sorprendentemente, una definizione simile a quella che sto per riprodurre non sono riuscita a trovarla né per "degeneracy" (inglese), né per "degeneración" (spagnolo) e neanche per "degeneració" (catalano) su nessun dizionario in queste altre lingue. Ho a casa el [*Diccionari de matemàtiques i estadística*](https://books.google.es/books/about/Diccionari_de_matem%C3%A0tiques_i_estad%C3%ADsti.html?id=LQ5yPQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y), ma l'unica definizione dell'aggettivo "degenerat -ada" ("degenere") che riporta è quella che, secondo la mia esperienza, è la più frequente nell'ambito della matematica  (si veda più sotto) e non ha a che vedere con quello che appare sullo Zingarelli. La voce "degeneració" non si trova su questo dizionario di lessico di matematica in catalano.

Sulla ristampa 2011 della Dodicesima edizione del vocabolario Zingarelli che si può scaricare gratuitamente su Kindle ho trovato la seguente definizione del vocabolo "degenerazione" che mi ha stupita per il fatto che porti la marca "*mat.*":

> **3** (*mat*.) Condizione in cui due o più funzioni, stati o grandezze, generalmente distinte, sono coincidenti.

Nell'edizione del 2021 di questo vocabolario, come @DaG conferma in un suo commento, appare esattamente lo stesso.

Mi sembra che in questa accezione si stia affermando che si possa dire che c'è "degenerazione" quando accade che diversi casi di qualcosa siano indistinguibili l'uno dall'altro da un certo punto di vista che si sta studiando, indistinguibili nel senso che, come dice la definizione sopra riportata, sono matematicamente  coincidenti da questo punto di vista.

Il fatto è che personalmente ho usato e ho sentito usare il termine "degenerazione" con questo senso molte volte, ma sempre tra fisici. Be', non esattamente "degenerazione", perché non parlo mai di fisica né di matematica in italiano, ma "degeneració", "degeneración" o "degeneracy". L'ho usata e visto utilizzare in modo proprio in molti contesti di fisica. In contesti che non sono di fisica l'ho sentita usare tra fisici con il senso spiegato e, in particolare, chiamando "degenerazione" (in realtà "degeneració" o "degeneración", non sono sicura se anche "degeneracy") al numero di casi indistinguibili che si hanno. Ma ho sempre avuto la sensazione che, in questi contesti non di fisica, si stesse usando in un modo che si potrebbe qualificare come improprio nel senso che una persona senza una formazione di fisica non l'avrebbe capita (e anche perché si tratta di usi che non mi sembra di aver visto su libri o articoli).

Va bene, diciamo che non sempre in modo improprio perché conosco un contesto matematico in cui "degenerazione" si usa con questo senso, ma personalmente conosco soltanto questo contesto. Per questa ragione, la definizione dello Zingarelli, che sembra indicare che "degenerazione" con questo significato si usa in matematica di forma più ampia, ha destato la mia curiosità. E la mia domanda sarebbe, perlomeno in italiano, è veramente così? O si tratta semplicemente di un errore del dizionario?

Infatti, l'uso a cui mi riferisco è esattamente quello che si utilizza in meccanica quantistica. Vediamo se riesco a trovare il vocabolario matematico adatto per spiegarlo (scusatemi e correggetemi se potete se non riesco a farlo). Il contesto è quello degli autovalori e autovettori di un endomorfismo di uno spazio vettoriale. Si dice che c'è "degenerazione" quando a un autovalore corrisponde un numero più grande di uno di autovettori linearmente indipendenti. L'autovalore a cui accade questo è detto "autovalore degenere". La dimensione dell'autospazio vettoriale ("eigenspace") associato a questo autovalore degenere si chiama "degenerazione". Ma potrebbe essere che persino questa terminologia sia usata esclusivamente in testi di matematica pensati per fisici o per studenti di fisica, perché so che si usa anche "molteplicità" per questo stesso concetto (quello di cui ho parlato sarebbe la *molteplicità geometrica* dell'autovalore). Per esempio, in [questo libro](https://books.google.es/books?id=ibZKJFMV4BwC&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13&dq=autovalori+autovettori+degenerazione&source=bl&ots=bsF2O3x1A7&sig=ACfU3U2CMINcVBqBCi06olZ6qobHV9iHjQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwit_cz3yJXqAhUHkhQKHcY6BDIQ6AEwBHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=autovalori%20autovettori%20degenerazione&f=false) si usa il termine "degenerazione", ma il titolo del libro è *Metodi matematici della Fisica*.

So che l'aggettivo "degenere" si usa in matematica per qualificare concetti completamente diversi dell'idea che ho descritto, molti associati alla nozione di "caso limite" o, per fare un altro esempio, si può parlare di una forma bilineare non degenere (o degenere). Ma non mi riferisco a niente di tutto questo (a meno che non ci sia una connessione con l'idea sopra spiegata che io non so vedere).

Difatti, lo Zingarelli  (l'edizione che ho io, ma anche, come conferma @DaG in un commento, quella del 2021) ha per l'aggettivo "degenere" solo due accezioni: quella di uso comune e questa:

> 2 (*fis*.) Detto di sistema fisico che presenta una degenerazione; in particolare, in meccanica quantistica, riferito a stati distinti ma aventi la stessa energia.

Questa seconda accezione, che ha la marca d'uso "*fis*.", sembra rimandare alla definizione di "degenerazione" che ho riprodotto all'inizio della domanda, fatto che mi fa sospettare che anche quella dovrebbe avere la marca "*fis*." invece di "*mat*.".

Sorprendentemente, lo Zingarelli non riporta l'accezione di "degenere" che secondo la mia esperienza in altre lingue, e anche in italiano secondo affermano alcuni commenti, è la più frequente nell'ambito della matematica. Traducendo dal catalano dal dizionario di matematica sopra citato, sarebbe questa:

> Detto del caso limite di qualche tipo di oggetto che equivale a un tipo più semplice, facendo spesso che un coefficiente o un parametro prenda il valore zero.  Un punto è il caso degenere di un cerchio di raggio zero.

Alcuni mesi fa, mi è capitato di discutere con una persona del lavoro di alcuni studenti su un problema che aveva per contesto il [gioco del Set](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(card_game)). A un certo punto della discussione, il mio interlocutore, che è fisico, usò la parola "degenerazione" (la parola "degeneració" in realtà, perché stavamo parlando in catalano) e io non ebbi nessun problema a capire a cosa si riferiva. Sono convinta, però, che si trattasse di un uso impropio del vocabolo. Ma in quel momento mi venne la curiosità di sapere se un "non fisico" l'avrebbe capito ed ebbi l'idea di chiederlo su [Spanish.SE](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/34512/) (spiegando che avevamo parlato in spagnolo, cosa che non è vero, ma la stessa conversazione si potrebbe aver svolto in castigliano usando "degeneración"). L'unica risposta che ho ricevuto non è del tutto completa, ma sembra indicare che il vocabolo spagnolo "degeneración" abbia il significato che ho riprodotto all'inizio di questo post esclusivamente nell'ambito della fisica oppure di testi di matematica pensati per fisici o studenti di fisica.

Poi, ho cercato di domandare un po' in giro  ad alcuni amici (a pochi: in condizioni di normalità avrei potuto chiedere a più persone) se avevano usato o visto usare il termine "degeneració" col senso spiegato all'inizio di questo post in contesti di matematica. Due matematiche e due insegnanti di matematica che non sono né matematici né fisici mi hanno detto di no. Queste amiche matematiche hanno confermato di aver sempre usato "molteplicità" (in realtà "multiplicitat", "multiplicidad" o "multiplicity" perché non parlano italiano) e mai "degenerazione" nel contesto degli autovalori degeneri di un endomorfismo di uno spazio vettoriale. Soltanto i miei amici fisici hanno detto di sì, in questo stesso contesto (ma, va be', si tratta di un contesto familiare a qualsiasi persona che abbia studiato meccanica quantistica).

Potrebbe essere semplicemente che, per qualche sorta di errore, la marca d'uso che appare nell'accezione dello Zingarelli sopra citata dovesse essere "(*fis*.)" invece di "(*mat*.)" perché l'ambito in cui si usa "degenerazione" in questo senso sia la fisica e non la matematica?

Comment: Ho accesso (a pagamento) all'ultima edizione dello Zingarelli, quella 2021, e confermo che la definizione che citi continua a essere presente immutata. L'aggettivo “degenere” ha solo due accezioni: quella comune e “2 (fis.) detto di sistema fisico che presenta una degenerazione; in particolare, in meccanica quantistica, riferito a stati distinti ma aventi la stessa energia”, che sembra simile a quella di cui parli tu. La cosa curiosa è che non è presente il senso più generale, ma pur sempre limitato alla matematica e alla fisica, che si applica ai casi limite di cui dicevi [segue]

Comment: [segue] cioè soluzioni, coniche, forme etc. degeneri. Manca comunque qualcosa da qualche parte...

Comment: @DaG:  Anch'io ho "degenere" sullo Zingarelli definito in questo modo, con soltanto queste due accezioni. E immagino che nell'accezione 2, in "Detto di sistema fisico che presenta una degenerazione", per "degenerazione" si debba capire l'accezione 3 che ho riportato.  Quello che mi stupisce è che l'accezione 3 abbia la marca "*mat.*". E poi, come hai detto, che né in "degenerazione" né in "degenere" non ci sia nessuna accezione con la marca "*mat.*" che dica qualcosa simile a "detto del caso limite di qualche tipo di oggetto" che credo sia più comune.

Comment: Uno dei miei amici mi ha detto di aver trovato su [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(mathematics)) che le radici di un polinomio si chiamano "degeneri" quando sono uguali: "Roots of a polynomial are said to be degenerate if they coincide, since generically the *n* roots of an *n*th degree polynomial are all distinct". Veramente io non credo di aver mai usato "degenerazione" (tradotto alle mie lingue): ho usato sempre "molteplicità" ("multiplicity", "multiplicidad", "multiplicitat").

Comment: Mi pare che la definizione non sia ben centrata, per quanto riguarda la matematica. Una conica è *degenere* quando consiste di due rette (distinte o anche coincidenti); un triangolo è *degenere* quando un vertice appartiene al segmento congiungente gli altri due (in altre parole, i vertici sono allineati). Se in fisica si dice *degenere* per un autovalore multiplo, non so; in matematica non l'ho mai sentito.

Comment: @egreg:  Veramente, non ho molta idea di cosa si dica in italiano. Si usa "degeneracy" ("degeneración" / "degeneració"), ma è vero che si usa anche "multiplicity" ("multiplicidad" / "multiplicitat"). Non so cosa abbia motivato la definizione dello Zingarelli, però.

Comment: @egreg: Forse la definizione dello Zingarelli ha la marca "(*mat*.)", ma veramente dovrebbe avere la marca "(*fis*.)".

Comment: @egreg: Probabilmente sia una terminologia di fisici: l'ho trovata in un libro che ha per titolo *Metodi matematici della Fisica* (l'ho aggiunto alla domanda).

Comment: @DaG: Sono ogni volta più convinta che si tratti di un errore del dizionario (alla voce "degenere" appare "fis." e non "mat.": probabilmente alla voce "degenerazione" dovrebbe anche apparire fis. invece di mat.; come hai menzionato, il dizionario non riporta niente sul significato di "degenere" nell'ambito della matematica). Errore che, come hai detto, appare ancora nell'ultima versione. Questo mi ha fatto riformulare la domanda. Ma forse scrivo tanto male in italiano che non si capisce cosa sto chiedendo. La domanda su Spanish.SE è nel fondo molto simile a questa e, a quanto pare, si è capita

Comment: Non so se vale la pena, @DaG, ma forse cercherò di aggiungere alla domanda l'informazione del tuo primo commento.

Comment: Se vogliamo parlare di errori del dizionario, il più lampante è che nell'aggettivo “degenere” manca l'accezione matematica più generale, di cui parlava anche @egreg .

Comment: Sì, @DaG: su questo sono completamente d'accordo. Ma, se nelle due accezioni menzionate delle due voci apparisse la marca "fis.", questo vorrebbe dire che il dizionario starebbe riportando l'accezione che si usa in fisica, cosa che, a me personalmente sembrerebbe benissimo. Mi pare che adesso  riporti solo una grande confusione. Non importa, però (immagino sia soltanto una mia sciocchezza irrilevante).

Comment: @DaG: Ho cercato di aggiungere alla domanda quello che hai detto nei commenti, ma non so se sono riuscita a farmi capire.

Comment: @egreg: In inglese, "degenerate eigenvalues": https://www.ch.ntu.edu.tw/~byjin/course/ChemMath/handouts/degeneracy.pdf, https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0031-9120/2/1/307/pdf, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1315726/, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/309782/, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/787343/, https://people.chem.ucsb.edu/metiu/horia/OldFiles/LectureNotes115AFall09/Ch7QM09.pdf, ecc. Ma non saprei dire se è nomenclatura esclusiva di fisici.